CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory PHP+DOCKER+YII+MYSQL
Im fighting with this problem since last week.
I have a project in php 5.6 with YII V.1. Im using MySQL 8.3 because is the only one permitted for my mac architecture.
I set up the project in a Docker and everything looks fine until the app ask me for the credentials
to get in. Once i press submit i get this error:
/var/www/html/fw/1.1.16/framework/db/CDbConnection.php(399)

387                 throw new CDbException('CDbConnection.connectionString cannot be empty.');
388             try
389             {
390                 Yii::trace('Opening DB connection','system.db.CDbConnection');
391                 $this-\>\_pdo=$this-\>createPdoInstance();
392                 $this-\>initConnection($this-\>\_pdo);
393                 $this-\>\_active=true;
394             }
395             catch(PDOException $e)
396             {
397                 if(YII_DEBUG)
398                 {
399                     throw new CDbException('CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: '.
400                         $e-\>getMessage(),(int)$e-\>getCode(),$e-\>errorInfo);
401                 }
402                 else
403                 {
404                     Yii::log($e-\>getMessage(),CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR,'exception.CDbException');
405                     throw new CDbException('CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.',(int)$e-\>getCode(),$e-\>errorInfo);
406                 }
407             }
408         }
409     }
410     /\*\*\


I checked into the docker that DB is running okey and db credentials are ok.
INFO ABOUT SOCKETS:
yktoo-db   | 2024-05-14T16:23:01.937766Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
yktoo-db   | 2024-05-14T16:23:01.937783Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.3.0'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Commu
.YML file:
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-app
        container_name: yktoo-app
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - /Users/xxx/Desktop/sar/var/www/html:/var/www/html
    db:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-db
        container_name: yktoo-db
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "xxxx"

Here is the fragment of code for the connection:


'db'=>array(                 
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=yktoodb;port=3306;dbname=phpmyadmin;
unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',                 'emulatePrepare' => true,                
'username' => 'xxx',              
'password' => 'xxx',                 
'charset' => 'utf8',`


Any ideas?? Thank u very much!
I tried changing the yktoo-db for the ip but it didnt work.
I tried using yktoo-db:3306  but it didnt work.

Your app is in one container and mysql database is on another container, meaning mysql is a remote database. Sockets can only be used for local connections, not for remote.
The solution is to use tcp connection with mysql container name or IP address as host name and whatever port you configured for mysql.

First of all thank u for helping me. Bad news, its still not working.

I'm sorry, but I can't help you with "it's not working" problem. If you got past this error with my help and stuck at a different error / unexpected behaviour, then please close this question down by accepting my answer. If you are still getting the same error message, then you need to provide a lot more details. Please bear in mind that we cannot see your docker network and therefore cannot tell you what the correct parameters are!

Please do not add further details in an answer. Edit your question.

I think your port is simply 3306, not 33060.
